# Getting a strange injector error - Unknown provider: bProvider <- b

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

After compiling my code, I'm getting a strange error that I don't recognize. Usually with an $injector error I get a specific module description, like $uibModal, or $resource, etc.

With this I just get this bProvider <- b.

Does anyone know how I might be able to troubleshoot this, or can anyone tell me what this is referring to?

I'm using grunt to compile and use uglify...

```
vendor.56b5173c.js:5 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: bProvider <- b
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=bProvider%20%3C-%20b
    at vendor.56b5173c.js:3
    at vendor.56b5173c.js:4
    at Object.d [as get] (vendor.56b5173c.js:4)
    at vendor.56b5173c.js:4
    at d (vendor.56b5173c.js:4)
    at e (vendor.56b5173c.js:4)
    at Object.g [as invoke] (vendor.56b5173c.js:4)
    at j.instance (vendor.56b5173c.js:5)
    at ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js:8
    at g (vendor.56b5173c.js:5)
```

Here is what my modal function looks like:

```
   var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
        templateUrl: 'questionsModal.html',
        controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance, SweetAlert) {

        $scope.close = function() {
            //self.showingExpenses = false;
            $uibModalInstance.close();
            videoId.play();
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: you've just missed one injection dependency in your app.js or some where in the code,please check for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes when you minify the js files:

What happens during minification is that **anotherService argument is being minified to 'b' (or something else).**

Angular will try to find the 'b' service, and when that fails it will try to find the 'bProvider' to provide the service.

Since neither of these are declared, you will receive the "Unknown provider" error.

To fix this, you should change all of the dependencies to strings:

**This syntax should be avoided:**

```
angular('myModule').service('myService', function(anotherService) {
  // ...
});
```

**This should be followed:**

```
angular('myModule').service('myService', ['anotherService', function(anotherService) {
        // ...
}]);
```

**This way when minification is done, it won't mess up the dependency injection.**

**This applies to any declaration, not just services.**

[this is the source of this answer](https://coderwall.com/p/eeqo7q/debugging-unknown-provider-error-in-angular)

Comment: I added my modal function. How would you add the format you suggested to the Modal Controll? It's different from adding a regular controller.

Comment: you can directly take the parent controller in the modal instance.

Comment: you can pass `controller: parentCtrl` and you can write the same method there.